# What is the difference between "closed" and "on hold"?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I've noticed that some questions are "closed" (e.g.: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/styling-pdf-download-link-field), while others are "on hold" (e.g. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82304/pdf-content-search-module).

It is not clear to me what the *difference* between these two statuses are.  E.g.: both statuses seem to the result of voting, and both seems to be eligible for reopening if it is "reworded to fit the rules in the help center".

So why is a question put "on hold" instead of "closed"?
And is there a pratical difference between being "on hold" instead of "closed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main practical difference is that during on hold period each edit by OP sends question to the reopen review queue. After that it must be done by moderator or someone who will actually vote to reopen. [See this stacoverflow meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188007/how-long-will-a-question-be-in-on-hold-status/188009#188009).

Answer (score 3):

When a question is voted to be closed, and it gets the necessary number of votes, it is first shown as *on hold* for five days, and then it is shown as *closed*. The only exceptions are questions closed as duplicates, which are always shown as *duplicate*.

*On hold* is used to make users understand that the status is not definitive, and the question can still be re-opened; it is *on hold*, waiting for the question to be edited and put into shape.

#### References

- [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)